# repaint() JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am currently trying to understand the `paintComponent()` and `repaint()` methods, but I just can't. I am having a panel with a button. What I want to do is when I click the button to clear the panel (remove the button) and maybe resize it and also, add a `JTextField`, but I simply don't know what to write inside the `paintComponent()` method.

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
public Test(){
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Buton.png");
    JLabel buton = new JLabel(image);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    buton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Buton-Pressed.png");
            buton.setIcon(image);
            remove(panel);
            revalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.add(buton);
    add(panel);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new Test();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public class Paint extends JPanel{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
}
```

This is the code for my mousePressed event after MadProgrammer's post :

```
buton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Buton-Pressed.png");
            buton.setIcon(image);
            removeAll();
            add(new JTextField("Big text field"));

           Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Test.this);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
```

But i am getting this error, at window.pack():

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AppPackage.Test$1.mousePressed(Test.java:34)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: From the way you described what you are trying to do, there is no reason to use painting. Haven't you tried adding a JTextField to the GUI? Clearly you must know how to add components because you did `panel.add(buton);` and `add(panel);`. If you don't know how to do this, then you should [review the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) instead of asking us to teach you these basic concepts. Your sample code also contains syntax errors. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to add a JTextField while removing the button.(tried remove(buton) and removeAll() but didnt worked) and also resize the frame. Also , it contains syntax errors because i edited it here quickly. It works without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `paintComponent` doesn't have anything to do with component management and should NEVER be used to add or remove components from a UI
2. `MouseListener` is the wrong listener to use with a `JButton`, a button may be triggered by the user using the key board, key board short-cut AND the mouse as well as programmatically, instead use a `ActionListener`

Start by taking a closer look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

So, based on your reqiurements, something like...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Big Button");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    removeAll();
                    add(new JTextField("Big text field"));
                    Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TestPane.this);
                    window.pack();
                    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

    }

}
```

Should work just fine

If you really want to understanding how painting works in Swing, then you need to take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: I am not having a JButton, i am having a JLabel. Thanks for your answer. I will test it, and edit this post

Comment: So i edited my main post for you to see what error i get. Basically i created a JLabel in order to create a custom button that changes when entered,exited and pressed.

Comment: You do realise that `JButton` already has `rollOver` support?

Comment: The only reason you will get a `null` result from `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TestPane.this);` is because `Test` is not attached to a window

Comment: I know it has rollOver support, but i dont like its design.I figured it out. Why can't i add now frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); ?

Comment: *"What do you mean by window ? JFrame ?"* - Yes. *"I know it has rollOver support, but i dont like its design."* - Then write a look and feel delegate (skin) which achieves what you need for a `JButton` and save yourself the effort of having to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Don't use `Test.this`, `Test` is already a `JFrame`, if you want to find the window a component is attached to, use the the `JTextField` you just added or `Test.this` directly (without `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`)

Comment: Everything is great, Thanks for your time and kind answer !